# How to close slide out drawer without clicking the toggle button (pure css/html build)

Tags: html, css, menu, slide

I'd like to be able to close by slide out menu without having to click on the toggle button. I've read through a lot of other posts that are similar, but I haven't been able to implement anything that works.

I've attached the html and css used so far. Thank you for any help!

```css
html {
    background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
#menu {
    display:block;
    background-color:#798d64;
    width:256px;
    min-height:100%;
    top:0;
    z-index:9999;
    position:fixed;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

#menu .toggle {
    top:40px;
    left:256px;
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#798d64;
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

#toggle {
    display:none;
}
/*pushing menu off canvas*/
#menu {
    left:-256px; /*must be same as width*/
    -webkit-transition:left 1s;
    -moz-transition:left 1s;
    -o-transition:left 1s;
    transition:left 1s;
}
#toggle:checked + #menu {
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition:left 1s;
    -moz-transition:left 1s;
    -o-transition:left 1s;
    transition:left 1s;
}
/*menu content*/
#menu span {
    display:block;
    font-size:22px;
    margin:20px 10px;
    background-color:#798d64;
    color:#fff;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#menu ul li {
    font-size:19px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
#menu ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}
#menu ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#798d64;
}
#menu ul ul li {
    background-color:none;
}
#menu ul li a:hover,
#menu ul ul li a {
    padding:10px 10px 10px 30px;
}
#menu ul ul li a:hover {
    padding:10px 10px 10px 60px;
}
#menu ul li a,
#menu ul li a:hover,
#menu ul ul li a,
#menu ul ul li a:hover {
    -webkit-transition:padding 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:padding 0.5s;
    -o-transition:padding 0.5s;
    transition:padding 0.5s;
}
/*hiding checkboxes, labels visible*/
input[id^="dropdown"],
ul[class^="dropdown"] {
    display:none;
}
input[id^="dropdown"]:checked + ul[class^="dropdown"] {
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       
        <title>GLI Nav</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="glinav.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>       
    <body>
        <!-- Checkbox to show/hide the navigation menu -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" value="toggle" id="toggle">
     
        <!-- navigation menu container -->
        <section id="menu">
     
            <!-- Lable for #showmenu to hide the menu/uncheck the checkbox -->
            <label class="toggle" for="toggle"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-bars"></i></label>
         
            <!-- Menu content -->
            <nav class="menuContent">
                <span>Navigation Links</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-home">  Home</a></li>
                    <li><label for="dropdown-1" class="dropdown-1"><a><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>  Be Inspired<i style="float:right" class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="menu" id="dropdown-1" />
                            <ul class="dropdown-1">
                            <li><a href="#"> Bel Marin Keys</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Belvedere<i style="float:right" class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Piedmont</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> San Francisco</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> San Rafael<i style="float:right" class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Tiburon</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Windsor</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-tree">  Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-newspaper-o">  Advice & News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-users">  About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-envelope-o">  Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
 
        </section> <!-- /#menu -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
#toggle:checked + #menu {
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition:left 1s;
    -moz-transition:left 1s;
    -o-transition:left 1s;
    transition:left 1s;
}
```

to this:

```
#toggle + #menu:hover {
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition:left 1s;
    -moz-transition:left 1s;
    -o-transition:left 1s;
    transition:left 1s;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oz5ohvwc/)

It you don't have to click on the element, you just have to hover it to make the menu appear, and the hiding-back will be done by the CSS when not being hovered automatically :)

Using JQuery:

Change this:

```
#toggle:checked + #menu {
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition:left 1s;
    -moz-transition:left 1s;
    -o-transition:left 1s;
    transition:left 1s;
}
```

to this:

```
#toggle + #menu {
    -webkit-transition:left 1s;
    -moz-transition:left 1s;
    -o-transition:left 1s;
    transition:left 1s;
}
```

This is the JQuery part:

```
$('html').click(function() {
   $("#toggle + #menu").css("left", "-256px");
});
$('#toggle + #menu').click(function(event){
    $(this).css("left", "0");
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});

$("label > a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().siblings("ul[class^='dropdown']").slideToggle();
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo with JQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/oz5ohvwc/3/)

Comment: I suppose the issue with making that change is that it would not be click friendly for mobile? (Since you can't hover) Am I missing something maybe?

Comment: @mmurphy I agree. But then, on a mobile device, how would you expect the page to know when the use is done with the menu and that it needs to be closed again, without clicking again? :) (Can easily be fixed with js/jquery, not that direct with pure html+css :P )

Comment: I figured jquery would be necessary for this, and would be happy to add it in - that's where I get caught up - my jquery writing skills are still poor at best ;)

Comment: @mmurphy I added the JQuery solution as well to the answer, have a look at the attached [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/oz5ohvwc/1/) :)

Comment: Thank you! But I did notice that breaks my submenu drop downs. Ideas? You've been a great help.

Comment: @mmurphy Sure :) I updated the answer and link to an updated JSFiddle. Have a look at it and let me know :)